# SocketTimeoutException on first HTTP call

Tags: java, android, http, loopj

I am getting `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` when I invoke the HTTP get, put, post or delete. But then when I click the button again to make another HTTP call, then it is successful. It seems that the `AsyncTask/doInBackground` doesn't fail like this. But the first HTTP call fails made using the LoopJ HTTP library. A button is hooked to invoke the below method. `On my first click`, I get the above `exception`, but when I click again, it is successful. Below is the log cat.

```
private void updateStatus(View view) {
        final int currentItemPosition = listView.getPositionForView(view);
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view;
        System.out.println("radioButton.getText(): " + radioButton.getText());
        System.out.println("currentItemPosition: " + currentItemPosition);
        status.set(currentItemPosition, radioButton.getText().toString());
        String url = "http://taskmgr-api.herokuapp.com/tasks/" + id.get(currentItemPosition);
        String contentType = "application/json";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("description", description.get(currentItemPosition));
            jsonObject.put("status", status.get(currentItemPosition));
            jsonObject.put("priority", priority.get(currentItemPosition));
            jsonObject.put("duedate", dueDate.get(currentItemPosition));
            jsonObject.put("id", id.get(currentItemPosition));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("json String: " + jsonObject.toString());
        StringEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(7000);
        client.put(context, url, entity, contentType, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                System.out.println("response: " + response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }



03-27 08:23:06.181: W/System.err(4979): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
03-27 08:23:06.181: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
03-27 08:23:06.181: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-27 08:23:06.191: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
03-27 08:23:06.191: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
03-27 08:23:06.191: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
03-27 08:23:06.191: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
03-27 08:23:06.201: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
03-27 08:23:06.211: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
03-27 08:23:06.211: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-27 08:23:06.211: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-27 08:23:06.211: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
03-27 08:23:06.211: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
03-27 08:23:06.221: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
03-27 08:23:06.221: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-27 08:23:06.221: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-27 08:23:06.221: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-27 08:23:06.221: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
03-27 08:23:06.231: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-27 08:23:06.241: W/System.err(4979):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:74)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:91)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-27 08:23:06.251: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-27 08:23:06.261: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-27 08:23:06.261: W/System.err(4979):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-27 08:23:06.261: W/System.err(4979):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Also, this error doesn't seem to be consistent. I have deleted the application and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase your timeout time may be internet is too slow to establish connection i.e try this

```
 client.setTimeout(70000);//or u can set any time in this
```

Comment: bcoz i faced same and then i increase my timeout and it fixed that time just try wd this